# Unable to install packages on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: apt, software-installation, 16.10

```
root@sagar-Lenovo-Product:~# apt install git
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package git is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'git' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: i tried it but but it shows no command erroe

Comment: You're using a very old version of Ubuntu which reached its end of life in July 2017. All packages for 16.10 are now hosted at old-releases. Did you follow the steps to modify sources.list? What have you tried? Please [edit] your question and paste the error message.

Comment: In addition to what @Kulfy said, please consider updating to a supported release. Your old release is easily compromised and can be used as everything from a spam relay node to a botnet participant.

Comment: so now what should i do ,  my pc is not supporting any other version. i've tried sudo apt update , sudo apt get upgrade , sudo apt get install vim , nothing works

Comment: Reinstalling a supported release is the best you can do.